# how to pass variable from main folder as property in module.css in React

Tags: css, reactjs, styling

In react project using module.css styling I want to make a main folder with variables commonly used for example file variable.js where I will have

```
export const colors = {
    buttonBackground:"#FFFFFF"
}
```

I want to pass it to certain classes. Will it work if for example in list.module.css file I will write:

```
import {colors} from "..."

.complete {
   background-color:${colors.buttonBackground}
}
```

Or it should be coded in different way ?
Sorry I don't have possibility now to test it on my own that's why I write and describe it.

thanks

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case you need to use some js constants you can have a look at JSS which is a way to write [css in js](https://cssinjs.org/), you can integrate JSS in your react app using this [guide](https://cssinjs.org/react-jss/?v=v10.3.0#jss-integration-with-react)